# my query syntax error

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB','Data Source='+@SERVER_IP+';User ID=sa;Password=xxx').'EXEC '+@DB_NAME+' .dbo.get_MY'
```

What is wrong with this query?

Here is the error:

> Incorrect syntax near '+'. Expecting')'

Answer (score 2):

You have a syntax error here:

```
User ID=sa;Password=xxx')
```

It should be

```
User ID=sa;Password=xxx)'
```

So you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLOLEDB','Data Source='+@SERVER_IP+';User ID=sa;Password=xxx) EXEC '+@DB_NAME+'.dbo.get_MY'
```

Comment: Data Source='+@SERVER_IP+';User ID=sa;Password=xxx) EXEC '+@DB_NAME+' .dbo.get_MY'   again error +@DB_NAME

Comment: remove the space between `' .dbo`

Comment: In your third statment, you do not have a `'` after `Password=xxx`

Answer (score 0):

You have an dangling single quote after xxx.  Your quotation marks are out of balance.